# Can't set PTR record for IPv6 address for Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-compute-engine

I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM, it has a public ipv4 IP and a public external ipv6 IP.
In the console, I input the PTR record: **blabla.mywebsite.com.** (the domain is already verified) both for ipv4 and ipv6 in the **public DNS PTR record** field, and ipv4 works normally, but ipv6 will return:

> Invalid value for field 'resource.name': 'External IPv6'. Access config name is immutable.

screenshot of my config 1

[image: 1]

screenshot of my config 2

[image: 2]

Is that mean currently I can't add ptr records for an ipv6 IP? or is there any wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Try using the CLI to update the access-config (--ipv6-public-ptr-domain): https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/update-access-confige

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by running a gcloud command in Cloud Shell.

> gcloud compute instances update-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME]
> --public-ptr --ipv6-public-ptr-domain [DOMAIN_NAME]

Although this did add an IPv6 PTR record, in the console we can't see it.

Thanks [@john-hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for answering this.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior seems to be flaky. I was able to set a PTR record for IPv6, but then I noticed it got lost, I suspect when the VM was stopped and restarted again. Now I'm not able to set it again, I can run the command above without errors, but the PTR record never shows up, hours later the rDNS lookup still returns the `bc.googleusercontent.com` generic name.

Comment: Also, rDNS lookup via the VM default DNS server 169.254.169.254 returns NXDOMAIN for IPv6 PTR, not even the generic name.
IPv6 is still new in GCP, bugs need to be fixed, no way to reserve an IPv6 either.